# What motivation is behind CheckStyle "inner type last" rule?

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

I'm re-evaluating SONAR code quality rules after upgrade to 4.4 and here is strange CheckStyle rule called 'inner type last' which is part of [class design](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html) group and actually recommends to place inner classes AFTER everything including methods.

What motivation is behind this? I never expected someone to consider this approach as useful but maybe I have missed serious ideology? Checkstyle rule definition doesn't provide any ground neither quick googling (maybe I searched wrong way). Could you please point from where this comes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ... this is indeed a mostly useless rule, especially because it cannot currently (5.7) be configured to enforce inner classes being declared at some other position than at the end. It can safely be disabled, I think.

However, it *is* the only way to enforce this part of the source file structure, so if you cannot be sure that everybody has her/his formatter properly configured, you might even want this. (Personally, I prefer inner types at the top, so that I know what they are when I read the code that's using them.)

The Checkstyle rules were originally focused on the [Sun Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) (1999), which did not say where inner classes should go. Also, the newer and popular [Google Java Style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) (2014) has no opinion on this. Checkstyle even has a [DeclarationOrder](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#DeclarationOrder) check, which also cannot check inner class position.

So I guess someone finally said this had to end and added [InnerTypeLast](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#InnerTypeLast). And there we have it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This rule assumes that inner types are "side" types that deal only with internal details of the enclosing type, and so that it's not worth showing those details at the very beginning of the source file to not focus attention on them.

IMO, the only (very little) value of this rule is to ensure consistency of code structure across your source code.